# How can I include one js file to another?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
.....
```

which I **cannot** change because of some objective reasons (so it's not possible to change script type to "module" like I saw in other answers). I also have `../init.js` file with a single function:

```
function init()
{
    ...
}
```

And now, I want access to the `init` function from ../script.js. So how can I do that and is this possible at all?
That's what I've tried inside `../script.js` file:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');        
script.src = "../init.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);

window.onload = init;
```

But that wouldn't work, because the browsers say that `init` is undefined

**UPD.:**
The problem is that now the `init` function is located directly inside ../script.js, but we want to move it into a separate file so that other scripts could use it as well and not produce duplicates

Comment: You can just call the `init()` function directly. It doesn't matter where the function was defined, it all lives "inside the browser" in the end. What problem do you want to solve with this, I have the feeling that this is not exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: It might be easiest to use something like webpack to automatically compile all necessary scripts into one file.

Comment: @cloned, it should be not only in onload, but in onresize and oncomplete too. I just simplified the code

Comment: So why can't you put the initialization of the event handlers _into_ init.js as well? `function init() {...}; window.onfoobar = init;` That `window.load` will still fire, when you load the script asynchronously like that, is rather doubtful. But that probably won't be the case with the version you attempted to implement either. But you could check the document's `readyState`, and based on that decide whether you want to call `init` directly, or still assign it as a load handler at this point.

Comment: @CBroe, I can't put an initialization into init.js because other scripts depending on it will use init function in different contexts (they may not use it for initialization at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `onload` listener to the script you're appending. When that fires, you know your init() function is defined.

```js
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "../init.js";

// Add an event listener for the 'load' event
script.onload = function() {
    console.log("Script loaded and ready");
    // You can now use init() as you'd like
};

document.head.appendChild(script);
```